# php vars are updating but javascript function shows allways first value

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php class that set values and updates them. I use getters methods to access those varibles from a javascript function and show them in screen. My problem is when I launch that javascript code, my vars are shown allways with the first values they get. I've checked them and they are up to date when I call `myCreateFunction();` but is like this function launches before the php vars are updated. I'm new in javascript and some help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
<?php    
    class TableRows {

        public $offerId = 0;

        public function setOfferId(){
            $this->offerId ++;
        }
        public function getOfferId(){
            $this->offerId;
        }

    }

    $tb = new TableRows(); 
?>
<script>
    function myCreateFunction(string) {
        var offerId =  '<tr><th>'+<?php echo json_encode($tb->getOfferId()); ?>+'</th></tr>';
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = offerId;
    }
</script>
<script>
    myCreateFunction();
</script>
<?php
    $tb->setOfferId();
?>
<script>
    myCreateFunction()
</script>
```

Comment: php is a html page preprocessor ... it generates a page, and spits it out to your browser ... there is no two way communication  like you think you are doing ... `$tb->setOfferId();` - that will result in a number in the javascript, the function would've been run before the page stared loading ... look at the source of the page in your browser to see what I mean

Comment: Php cant manipulate the code at the client side level. You need to handle the variables and change them in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because `myCreateFunction` is being rendered by your browser on your second call. PHP (server-side) has nothing in common with JavaScript (client-side). Don't mix your code like that.

Instead, you can use setters, getters, and then pass the value to your JavaScript function as parameter.

Comment: so the way to pass params would be like this??->
$tb->setOfferId;
$offerID = $tb->getOfferId;
<script>myCreateFunction(<?php echo $offerID ;?>);</script>

Comment: Yes, that's a way to do this. But I think that you even can move your code to client-side, because you don't have (in sample code) any code which requires server to proceed it.

Comment: I'm doing some sql queries in my class that's why I have to use vars allready setted up in php before to pass them to javascript, thanks a lot for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem in understanding where you are in your code (in javascript or in php). `$tb->setOfferId();` does not modify anything in your javascript. So the second call to `myCreateFunction()` will be exactly the same.